# Inequality between $L^p$ norm and Schwartz seminorm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, schwartz-space

Let $u\in \mathscr{S}$ (Schwartz space). I can prove easily that $u$ is in $L^p$ for every $p$. But I cannot prove the following. Let $\{p_k\}$ be the family of seminorms that defines the topology of the Schwartz space

$$p_k(\psi)=\max_{|\alpha|,|\beta|\leq k} ||x^\alpha D^\beta \psi||_{L^{\infty}}$$

Then there is a sufficiently large $N$ such that
$$||u||_{L^p}\leq Cp_N(u)$$
for an opportune costant $C$.

Comment: I've corrected.

Comment: On the ball of radius one about the origin bound $|u|^p \le \|u\|_\infty^p$. On the remainder of space, write $u = x^{-\alpha} x^{\alpha} u$ with $\alpha$ large enough so that $x^{-\alpha}$ is in $L^p$ on the complement of the unit ball

Comment: I still can't see it. Could you write the steps explicitely please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The topology on $\mathcal{S}$ is generated by an equivalent sequence of pseudonorms:

$$
\rho_m(\phi):=\sup_{\substack{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\\|\beta|\leq m}} |(1+|x|^2)^m\partial^\beta\phi(x)|,\qquad m\in\mathbb{Z}_+
$$

For $\phi\in\mathcal{S}$ and $1\leq p<\infty$,
$$
|\phi(x)|=(1+|x|^2)^n|\phi(x)|\frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^n}
\leq \frac{\rho_n(\phi)}{(1+|x|^2)^n},
$$
Thus
\begin{align*}
    \|\phi\|_p&\leq \Big(\int^\infty_0\frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^{np}}\,dx\Big)^{1/p}\rho_n(\phi)
  \end{align*}

Comment: Is it possible to do it with the family of seminorms that I'm using?

Comment: @Kandinskij: All you have to do now is to show that for each $n$ there is $K_n$ and $C_n>0$ such that $\rho_n\leq C_n\rho_K$.